No file name or line numbers in Visual Studio error list when using Intel oneAPI C++ compiler
I am using Visual Studio 2022 and Intel oneAPI 2025. When I compile in Visual Studio using the Intel compiler, errors in the Error List panel do not display a file name or line number. How do I enable this feature?
